# How to access a variable from .as file in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I coded my game in AS3 and I added highscores to it. I am really new to AS3 so I wrote code in frames, but to add highscores I had to have some code in .as file. The problem is that scores take 2-3 seconds to load, and if I click on the menu button before they load game freezes, so I need to check if function for loading highscores has finished in .as file. There is such a function there

```
class getUserRankCallBack implements App42CallBack {
    public function onSuccess(res: Object): void {
        if (res is Game) {
            var game: Game = Game(res);
            for (var i: int = 0; i < game.getScoreList().length; i++) {
                trace("user rank is : " + Score(game.getScoreList()[i]).getRank());
            }
        }
    }
    public function onException(excption: App42Exception): void {
        trace("Exception is : " + excption);
    }
}
```

so when it finishes I see the trace, but I can't seem to find what should I put in the if function to check if it's loaded in the frame code in the main .fla file... I tried making a new variable in .as file, like

```
var something:Number=1;
```

but if I try to trace something in the .fla it gives me access to undefined property, so I don't know how to do this and I think it's really simple.

Comment: make something public
`public var something:Number=1;`

Comment: You need to show the relationship between the as file and context where you want to check.